# Selenium Java 10 buttons with same text, same id, same class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dynamic-tables

I am trying to automate the webpage which has a table (dynamic in nature). It has 9 columns and 12 rows and 108 tabindex so far. I am trying to access 8th and 9th column for each row. Eight column has "Manage" buttons and 9th column has "Edit Buttons"
[Example of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNj97.png)

I have extracted the info like this :

[how i got the table info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfjZt.png)

```
int manageColumn = 8;   
int manage = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
     manage = (i-1)*(column.size()+1) + manageColumn;
     System.out.println("Manage button tabIndex number " + manage);
    }
System.out.println();

int editColumn = 9; 
int edit = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
     edit = (i-1)*(column.size()+1) + editColumn;
     System.out.println("Edit button tabIndex number " + edit);
    }
```

}

Now I am having hard time using the list of manage and edit values that i am getting to incorporate it into my code below

Code for locating Manage button element on Webpage

[manage button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEUGg.png)

Code for locating Edit button element on Webpage

[edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UAsZ.png)

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Not `i <= rows` as you start from 1? Not sure what exactly you are looking for, maybe `function tabi(row, col) { var colsize = 13; return (row-1)*(colsize+1)+col; }`

Comment: I have all the unique info (value) for each button . but instead of writing driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[tabindex='value']") 10 times, I want to incorporate a loop which will run for all the values i have previously found using a for loop.

Comment: A nested loop would do to `for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++) { for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {`